# Macro is taking more time to copy content in Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have below code snippet that copies specific set of rows and paste it under another row in an excel sheet. Based on number of Cars, the sets copies will be changed.

Column B:E contains some data and Column H:K is what I will be copying and pasting under last row of Column B:E. and the values in column H:K are derived on formula. And these values depend on the car count(Range: CarCnt_counter) and it has around 18 rows to be copied. So if car count is 20, loop execute 20 times and copy 18 rows 20 times with value changed based on car count. Range CarFields holds the data in column H:K and range Rowmap_Last is determines based on a formula which is the last row number of column B:E

```
Worksheets("RowMapping").Select
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim CarCnt As Integer
Dim Total As Integer
Total = Range("CarCnt_count")

For CarCnt = 1 To Total
    Range("CarCnt_counter") = CarCnt
    Worksheets("RowMapping").Calculate
    Range("CarFields").Copy     

    Range("B" & Range("RowMap_Last").Value).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next CarCnt
```

Above is the code that does this. I believe Calculate method here in loop is slowing it up. I even moved the calculate out of the loop giving below code

```
Application.Calculation = XlCalculationAutomatic
```

This still did not improve performance. Any help on this would deeply be appreciated.

Comment: if I don't do Calculate cells under the range CarFields will not get updated. This is based on the value in CarCnt_counter

Answer (score 2):

Copy and Paste on a loop is slower. Try the following Range.Value = Range.value method instead of copy and paste.

```
Dim CarCnt As Integer
Dim Total As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("RowMapping")
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False
        Total = Range("CarCnt_count")
        For CarCnt = 1 To Total
                Range("CarCnt_counter") = CarCnt
                Range("CarFields").Value = Range("B" & Range("RowMap_Last")).Value
        Next CarCnt
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Disabling Screen update increases the calculation speed.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Comment: if I don't do Calculate cells under the range CarFields will not get updated. This is based on the value in CarCnt_counter

Comment: Just add .Calculate under range. That should re-calculate entire worksheet once again.

Comment: I added this. But looks like its no copying the content. Also I need to copy to range Range("B" & Range("RowMap_Last") from Range("CarFields"). So i changed your locig as below : Range("B" & Range("RowMap_Last")).Value = Range("CarFields").Value. Blank value gets copied